# how to create a time series for various observations

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to create different time series found in numerous observations in the following dataset for two species of fish, so that I can perform autocorrelation analysis.The data has been imported into R as: `BF<-read.table("butterflyfish_database_NEW.txt",header=T)`. I have provided a sample of this information below.

I am pretty stuck on how to conduct a time series for each observation (Obs_N) for x position (x) and y positions (y). In other words, a time series dataset is needed for x and y separately for observation 1 (rows 2-110), then again for x and y for observation 2 (109-136) and so on.

As an example, I have tried using `x.ts<-(x,Time)`. This does not work, and even if it did it would only provide a time series for ALL of positions in x. I need to break this down based upon different observations.

This is a big ask but any help would be greatly appreciated.

`Species    Site    Obs_N   Time    x   y
Aus FG  1   30:00.0 206.44  100.09
Aus FG  1   30:30.0 205.89  101.34
Aus FG  1   31:00.0 206.38  103.53
Aus FG  1   31:30.0 206.22  106.87
Aus FG  1   32:00.0 204.79  107.93
Aus FG  1   32:30.0 202.85  108.06
Aus FG  1   33:00.0 202.85  108.06
Aus FG  1   33:30.0 202.85  108.06
Aus FG  1   34:00.0 202.84  108.05
Aus FG  1   34:30.0 202.85  108.06
Aus FG  1   35:00.0 202.85  108.06
Aus FG  1   35:30.0 203.56  108.61
Aus FG  1   36:00.0 206.13  107.45
Aus FG  1   36:30.0 207.53  106.22
Aus FG  1   37:00.0 207.05  103.49
Aus FG  1   37:30.0 206.86  100.33
Aus FG  2   00:00.0 207.44  106.78
Aus FG  2   00:30.0 207.60  106.61
Aus FG  2   01:00.0 208.33  103.72
Aus FG  2   01:30.0 207.35  102.57
Aus FG  2   02:00.0 206.30  102.27
Aus FG  2   02:30.0 206.43  101.60
Aus FG  2   03:00.0 206.73  100.66
Aus FG  2   03:30.0 206.50  101.11
Aus FG  2   04:00.0 206.63  100.95
Aus FG  2   04:30.0 206.27  102.02
Aus FG  2   05:00.0 207.93  105.83
Aus FG  2   05:30.0 207.15  106.98
Aus FG  2   06:00.0 206.28  107.32
Aus FG  2   06:30.0 204.70  108.36
Aus FG  2   07:00.0 203.41  107.97
Aus FG  2   07:30.0 202.63  107.76
Aus FG  2   08:00.0 201.13  107.85
Aus FG  2   08:30.0 198.74  107.60
Aus FG  2   09:00.0 197.41  106.45
Aus FG  2   09:30.0 196.77  106.12
Aus FG  2   10:00.0 195.98  105.92
Aus FG  2   10:30.0 196.15  106.18
Aus FG  2   11:00.0 196.55  105.97
Aus FG  2   11:30.0 197.02  106.35
Aus FG  2   12:00.0 197.93  107.17
Aus FG  2   12:30.0 198.57  107.11
Aus FG  2   13:00.0 200.24  108.01
Aus FG  2   13:30.0 202.16  107.62
Aus FG  2   14:00.0 204.16  108.12
Aus FG  2   14:30.0 206.72  106.96
Aus FG  2   15:00.0 207.14  106.58
Aus FG  2   15:30.0 207.76  106.85
Aus FG  2   16:00.0 207.97  106.20
Aus FG  2   16:30.0 207.60  106.09
Aus FG  2   17:00.0 207.86  106.03
Aus FG  2   17:30.0 208.46  104.95
Aus FG  2   18:00.0 208.60  104.68
Aus FG  2   18:30.0 208.53  104.44
Aus FG  2   19:00.0 208.17  103.21
Aus FG  2   19:30.0 207.70  99.42
Aus FG  2   20:00.0 208.30  99.23
Aus FG  2   20:30.0 207.16  99.32
Aus FG  2   21:00.0 206.92  99.67
Aus FG  2   21:30.0 207.48  99.66
Aus FG  2   22:00.0 207.02  99.98
Aus FG  2   22:30.0 207.76  99.61
Aus FG  2   23:00.0 206.64  100.06
Aus FG  2   23:30.0 207.19  100.18
Aus FG  2   24:00.0 206.71  100.38
Aus FG  2   24:30.0 206.35  100.70
Aus FG  2   25:00.0 208.12  105.47
Aus FG  2   25:30.0 207.33  106.37
Aus FG  2   26:00.0 206.43  107.17
Aus FG  2   26:30.0 206.95  106.39
Aus FG  2   27:00.0 203.66  107.68
Aus FG  2   27:30.0 203.12  107.59
Aus FG  2   28:00.0 201.67  107.75
Aus FG  2   28:30.0 199.64  107.16
Aus FG  2   29:00.0 197.32  106.01
Aus FG  2   29:30.0 195.46  105.45
Aus FG  2   30:00.0 194.87  104.49
Aus FG  2   30:30.0 194.65  103.70
Aus FG  2   31:00.0 194.29  103.09
Aus FG  2   31:30.0 194.47  104.16
Aus FG  2   32:00.0 194.92  105.08
Aus FG  2   32:30.0 197.23  105.36
Aus FG  2   33:00.0 198.08  106.82
Aus FG  2   33:30.0 199.23  107.27
Aus FG  2   34:00.0 199.41  107.61
Aus FG  2   34:30.0 200.02  107.44
Aus FG  2   35:00.0 201.61  107.50
Aus FG  2   35:30.0 203.89  108.03
Aus FG  2   36:00.0 204.65  107.88
Aus FG  2   36:30.0 205.10  108.24
Aus FG  2   37:00.0 205.45  108.16`

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that this data is stored in a `data.frame` called `dd`. The first issue is that R doesn't really have a class for just "time" so to make a time series it has to be converted to a proper date/time value. It looks like your value is just minutes and seconds. So we can paste on hours and R will use the current date to fill out the value

```
dd$DateTime <-as.POSIXct(paste("00:",dd$Time, sep=""), format="%H:%M:%S")
```

You didn't specify which library you were using for time series data, so i'll just assume `xts`. Now i'll split the data on the `Obs_N` variable and we will turn each subset into an `xts` object

```
tslist<-lapply(split(dd, dd$Obs_N), function(x) xts(x[,c("x","y")],x$DateTime))
```

This will create a list of `xts` objects. You can get to the series for `Obs_n==1` with `tslist[[1]]` and `Obs_n==2` with `tslist[[2]]`

Note that I left out `Species` and `Site`. They were all identical in your test data so i'm not sure how much they matter. But I'm not sure how to integrate factor variables into time series objects.